# APCS final project: Converting an audio file to a simpler MIDI file

Tags: audio

Lets say I have the audio file for Happy Birthday. I want to convert that audio file into an audio file that sounds like this : [happy birthday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3xfijEQufU).

First, I'd like to know if I have the ability to program this? Can a highschooler who's almost finished with APCS program this?

If I can:
How would I change the bpm of the song? I've searched through a bunch of websites, but they weren't very helpful.

I know that audio files can be represented in waveforms. How would I scan for each individual wave in an audio file (I need this to isolate the notes)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very ambitious project, actually. One reason is that it involves using digital signal processing tools like FFT (Fast fourier transforms) to analyze the sound to pick out the pitches. You might be able to find a library that can do this, but as far as coding such a tool, that would involve a steep learning curve.

If you would like to look further into this, there is a good online resource called "[The Scientists and Engineers Guide to Digital Signal Processing](https://dspguide.com/)". I was able to work through and understand the discrete fourier transform with only high school math (lots of trig) and a bit of calculus. It was a lift, though.

Trying to analyze rhythm is also no easy task. Even with advanced tools provided in professional notation system such as Finale, people have trouble playing rhythms in time well enough for the best transcription tools. Algorithms that "quantize" the beats help but also limit the amount of detail that can be included in the playback.

My guess is that as interesting and worthwhile as this project would be, to bring it to completion before the semester ends would require putting together prebuilt pieces. A lot of programming is done that way, these days.

If you scale the project back to something like just getting your code to analyze a short sample of a single note and give its pitch, that would be both impressive and doable with a lot of work. It could be done with a DFT algorithm instead of requiring FFT, reducing the amount of info you'd have to acquire first. That way, you'd only have to work your way up to understanding and implementing the material on [this link which is about calculating the DFT](http://www.dspguide.com/ch8/6.htm). Notice that there is example code in BASIC. The code examples throughout this book are a big help.